# Is it possible to pull values from other tabs for use in a formula?

Tags: formula

Suppose I have two sets of tabs - an accounts tab and a second tab that tracks an entity that has a relationship with the accounts tab (say something like stores for instance).

Suppose within this Stores tab there was a checkbox that said "Retail".

Is it possible for me to pull information from that Stores tab to put together a formula that would display relevant information on the Accounts page for Stores that have relationships with that account?

For instance

- Calculate how many stores in total are associated with this Account
- Calculate a percentage of how many of those stores are listed as "Retail" based on the binary value of the Retail checkbox located on the Stores tab

Any help is appreciated. I have attempted to research the topic but not had much luck in located the exact information that I'm looking for.

Comment: Is Account a parent or a child of Stores?

Comment: Stores would likely be a child of Accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a Master-Detail relationship between Account (parent) and Stores (child), then you can use Rollup Summary Fields to rollup the calculations of store information to the related account record.

Rollup Summary Field allow for filtering, so you would probably have a RSF for Total Stores, and one for Total Retail Stores on Account and then you could create a formula field on account that gave you the correct percentage.

Here is some good information about defining relationships between objects from the documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm

And here is the documentation on Rollup Summary Fields:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US

It's worth noting that tabs don't have relationships in Salesforce, only the underlying objects that the tabs represent actually have the relationships. Those relationships are defined on those objects via Lookup and/or Master-Detail fields. The tabs are just the visual display of the object that controls search visibility, tab visibility permissions, navigation, and views of the object data.

Comment: Beautiful! This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!